# IInternetBindInfoEx - When IE/Urlmon asks for it?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'd like input from the heavy-weights please. I'm so close to making my add-in work properly, but some little thing eludes me ... help needed.

Background: I'm writing a pluggable protocol that takes over http/https when the user is "logged-in" into the toolbar. For the record I know that it is not advisable to hook into http/https, but these are the business requirements. The toolbar is essentially a transparent proxy.

I am successfully intercepting calls to http/https classes, that Urlmon makes, providing my own sink and bind info classes, however I am still missing something to make it work 100%. Can't login to gmail for example, it says that my cookies are "mismatched". Anyway, back on topic: I recently discovered an extension to IInternetBindInfo - IInternetBindInfoEx.

Question: how and when do I hook into IInternetBindInfoEx?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a replacement implementation for the HTTP/HTTPS protocols is really hard. I strongly recommend you take a look at [Igor Tandetnik's Passthrough APP](https://github.com/salsita/passthruapp).

Comment: This project is already done. Passthrough APP was of great help as well as code for Google gears. Take a look at getcocoon.com.